# Left Join query with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have 3 tables:
`Group`, `Person` and `Workout`. `Group` is a foreign key to `Person`, and `Person` is a foreign key to `Workout`.
I want to select the list of all the people in a certain group, and if there was a workout between the given dates for that person, then also get the duration, if not, just make it null.

Not quite sure how to write the SQL, I'm stuck in something like this:

```
SELECT Person.id, Person.firstName, Workout.duration 
FROM Person LEFT OUTER JOIN Workout 
ON Person.id = Workout.person_id 
WHERE Workout.start_date BETWEEN %s AND %s 
AND Person.group_id = %s
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Your `where` clause is undoing the `left join`.  When there is no match, `start_date` is NULL, which fails the comparison.

Moving the condition to the `on` clause fixes this:

```
SELECT Person.id, Person.firstName, Workout.duration 
FROM Person LEFT OUTER JOIN Workout 
     ON Person.id = Workout.person_id and Workout.start_date BETWEEN %s AND %s 
where Person.group_id = %s
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple, yet I couldn't figure it out.